# How to check for consecutive timestamp in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I have a dictionary which has the values as follows:

```
{
'original_data': [{'1600995180': 64.71666666666667, '1600995240': 0.17222222222222222, '1600995300': 0.16111111111111112, '1600995360': 0.6666666666666666, '1600995420': 0.17222222222222222, '1600995480': 0.0, '1600995540': 0.0, '1600995600': 0.0, '1600995660': 0.0, '1600995720': 0.0, '1600995780': 0.0, '1600995840': 1.0, '1600995900': 1.0, '1600995960': 1.0, '1600996020': 0.0, '1600996080': 0.0, '1600996140': 1.0, '1600996200': 1.0, '1600996260': 1.0, '1600996320': 0.0, '1600996380': 0.0, '1600996440': 0.0, '1600996500': 0.0, '1600996560': 0.0, '1600996620': 0.0, '1600996680': 0.0, '1600996740': 0.0, '1600996800': 0.0, '1600996860': 0.0, '1600996920': 10.86944444444444, '1600996980': 106.88333333333331}],
'outliers': [0.16111111111111112, 0.17222222222222222, 0.17222222222222222, 0.6666666666666666, 10.86944444444444, 64.71666666666667, 106.88333333333331]
}
```

The `original_data` contains a list of values as `{timestamp: value}` . The outliers just contain the outlier `value` which is from the original_data.

I want to actually compare each `value` in the `outlier` and then see in the `original_data` if those values are occurring consecutively with the timestamp. The timestamp is 1 minute apart for each data point

Comment: why is `original_data` a list with only 1 element (a dict)

Answer (score 0):

```
def consecutively(data):
    values = data['original_data'][0].values()
    out = data['outliers']
    b = False
    for v in values:
        if v in out:
            if b:
                return True
            else:
                b = True
        else:
            b = False
    return False
```

This would work!

PS I'm not sure on the usage of the 'original_data' as a list with only 1 item, which is a dictionary. Why do not use a dict directly?

Comment: i also want to ensure that the timestamps are accounted for, since i want to check the consecutive

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion, which is to handle this in a pandas `DataFrame`.

I will call your original dictionary `data`. It's in a slightly odd format, but that can be handled easily:

```py
import pandas as pd  # pip install pandas if you don't have it

df = pd.DataFrame(data["original_data"]).T.reset_index()

df.columns = ["timestamp", "value"]  # change the column names to something descriptive

### OPTIONAL (convert UNIX timestamps to pandas Timestamp to makes things clearer)
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp, unit="s")
###

df["outlier"] = df.value.isin(data["outliers"])  # add a column to show whether a value was an outlier
```

At this point, you may be done! You can inspect `df` and see:

```
             timestamp       value  outlier
0  2020-09-25 00:53:00   64.716667     True
1  2020-09-25 00:54:00    0.172222     True
2  2020-09-25 00:55:00    0.161111     True
3  2020-09-25 00:56:00    0.666667     True
4  2020-09-25 00:57:00    0.172222     True
5  2020-09-25 00:58:00    0.000000    False
6  2020-09-25 00:59:00    0.000000    False
7  2020-09-25 01:00:00    0.000000    False
8  2020-09-25 01:01:00    0.000000    False
9  2020-09-25 01:02:00    0.000000    False
10 2020-09-25 01:03:00    0.000000    False
11 2020-09-25 01:04:00    1.000000    False
12 2020-09-25 01:05:00    1.000000    False
13 2020-09-25 01:06:00    1.000000    False
14 2020-09-25 01:07:00    0.000000    False
15 2020-09-25 01:08:00    0.000000    False
16 2020-09-25 01:09:00    1.000000    False
17 2020-09-25 01:10:00    1.000000    False
18 2020-09-25 01:11:00    1.000000    False
19 2020-09-25 01:12:00    0.000000    False
20 2020-09-25 01:13:00    0.000000    False
21 2020-09-25 01:14:00    0.000000    False
22 2020-09-25 01:15:00    0.000000    False
23 2020-09-25 01:16:00    0.000000    False
24 2020-09-25 01:17:00    0.000000    False
25 2020-09-25 01:18:00    0.000000    False
26 2020-09-25 01:19:00    0.000000    False
27 2020-09-25 01:20:00    0.000000    False
28 2020-09-25 01:21:00    0.000000    False
29 2020-09-25 01:22:00   10.869444     True
30 2020-09-25 01:23:00  106.883333     True
```

and this tells you what you want to know. Alternatively, if you want to explicitly flag whether an outlying value was preceded by another outlying value, you could do

```py
df["is_outlier_preceded_by_outlier"] = df.outlier & df.outlier.diff().eq(False)
```

and this creates a column whose value is `True` is the value was an outlier and was preceded by another outlier, and `False` otherwise.

`df.query("is_outlier_preceded_by_outlier")` will then return *only* those cases where it is `True`.

EDIT: alternatively (less obvious but more extensible)

```py
df["is_outlier_preceded_by_outlier"] = df.outlier.rolling(2).sum().eq(2)
```

will work too, and you can change 2 (in both places) to any number you like to look for runs of N consecutive outliers.

EDIT 2: so, if you want the values for every group of N consecutive outliers, it's a bit trickier:

```py
groups = df.outlier.diff().ne(0).cumsum()

is_part_of_long_group = df.outlier.groupby(groups).transform("size").ge(3)

df["one_of_many_outliers"] = is_part_of_long_group & df.outlier

df.query("one_of_many_outliers").value
```

First we're going to have to identify groups of identical values in the `outlier` column. `df.outlier.diff().ne(0).cumsum()` creates a series, which we'll use as a grouping index, with incrementally higher values every time the next value in the `outlier` column differs from the previous one.

We next group the `outlier` column by this 'index', and use the `transform` method to get the size of each group of consecutive values. Finally, we check whether the size of that group is greater than or equal to 3, i.e. we look for groups of consecutive values that are at least 3 items in length.

Note that whereas `agg("size")` would give us each group and its size, `transform("size")` gets the size of each group and maps it back onto the original `df.outlier` series.

Finally, we're not interested in consecutive non-outliers, so we check whether values are both outliers *and* part of a long group of consecutive equal values.

Comment: Lets say i want to check if 3 outliers are consecutive, what can i do for that

Comment: For that I would recommend `df.outlier.rolling(3).sum().eq(3)`. That series will be `True` for any case where something is the third consecutive outlier in a row (it'll work for any number, just change both 3s - in fact I wish I'd thought of it in the first place and will put it in the answer).

Comment: Ah no, not that,. so what i want to do is basically see if lets say 3 `True` are consecutive then i want to count all of the 3 and put it in a list outside the df .

Comment: The reason is , i have not just one dict but 10 dicts and i want to see if 3 values of outliers are consecutive in each of the original value, then i will just update that count in a list

Comment: So you want any record that forms part of a group of three consecutive outliers? For the future, it is good to have as much detail about what you want in the question as possible. Getting these groups is possible but I don't think it's trivial - I will add one option to my answer.

Comment: I've added a possible solution.